# Load static library in swift code

Tags: c++, ios, swift, xcode

I have a static library (.a file) written in c++ and compiled with xcode.
In the C++ code I have:

```
extern "C" void startA(const char * szCmdLne){
 //bla bla
}

extern "C" void stopA(){
  //bla bla
}
```

Now I'm writing an iOS SDK in swift 2 (in xcode). I want to load the library into the SDK and to call these 2 function (startA and stopA).

What is the right way to do it? i tried bridging but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

1)Link the static library in xcode at Build Phase -> Link Binary with libraries.

2)Add library header file in the swift project.

3)Need to create a bridging header to call library Api using (File > New > File), then select “Source” and click “Header File“.

4) Add 
    void stopA() 
    startA(const char * szCmdLne)
in bridging header file.

Now, You should able to call these APIs from your swift code.
Check this for more detail:
http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html#step2

Comment: Thanks! i manage to make it work without the bridging file, I declared the function in the umbrella header. The only issue is that these function are public so everyone that uses this SDK can see/call them. How can I make them private?